# wordpress pagination create wrong url

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

wordpress pagination create wrong url for second page

1st page abc.com/demo/abc/?page_id=81

2nd page abc.com/demo/abc/page/2/?page_id=86

i need url like first page in second page. when i click second page post it will redirect to same page.

```
> <div class="pagination"><?php echo paginate_links( array(
>                                         'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
>                                         'total'        => $arr_posts->max_num_pages,
>                                         'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
>                                         'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
>                                         'show_all'     => false,
>                                         'type'         => 'plain',
>                                         'end_size'     => 2,
>                                         'mid_size'     => 1,
>                                         'prev_next'    => true,
>                                         'add_args'  => array()
>                                     ) );
>                                ?>
>                             </div>
> 
> 
>           <?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
>                             $arr_posts = new WP_Query( array(
>                                  'post_type' => 'post',
>                                 'post_per_page' => 4,
>                                 'paged' => $paged
>                             ) );
>                         
>                         if ($arr_posts->have_posts()) :
>                             while ($arr_posts->have_posts()):
>                                 $arr_posts->the_post();
>                                 ?>
>                                 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 news-gal-itm">
>                                              <h4><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_link', true); ?>"> <?php the_title();
> ?> </a></h4>
>                                     <h5><?php echo get_the_date(); ?> at <?php echo get_the_time(); ?></h5>
>                                     <div class="row">
>                                         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 img-sec">
>                                             <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive
> pull-left')); ?>
>                                             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
>                                         </div>
>                                     </div>
>                                 </div>
>                                 
>                            <?php  endwhile; 
>                      
>                             
>                      
>                         endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto the wordpress admin and change the permalink structure first.

Setting->permalink and then select post name as the permalink and update the settings

Comment: then why your permalinks are creating like this 1st page abc.com/demo/abc/?page_id=81

2nd page abc.com/demo/abc/page/2/?page_id=86